# Rails 4 NoMethodError validate (bcrypt)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn, bcrypt

I am trying to launch my Rails 4 App in production (it is just a simple blog with a signin form for users from the database to be able to login and CRUD)

I am running nginx with unicorn and bcrypt for user authentication with has_secure_password on the User model. When I try to signin a user my production.log shows:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `authenticate' for nil:NilClass):
app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:9:in `create'
```

in my Sessions controller this block is what is calling the authenticate method:

```
user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    sign_in user
    redirect_to root_path
else
    flash.now[:warning] = "Invalid User/Password combination"
    render 'new'
end
```

unless I change the else statement to soemthing else I get the "Invalid User/Password combination" error message and it renders /sessions

What's really strange is that when I run User.find_by_email("user's email").authenticate("user's password") in rails console I get the user returned to me.

I am completely stumped as to why my user authentication works in development mode but not production!

Here is the github repo of a sample app experiencing the same problem:
https://github.com/sentrathis96/debug_app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was having was creating a user in the development database, not production. So on the production VPS I had to run `RAILS_ENV=production rails c` to create my user so there'd be a user record to login with.

Make sure to create the necessary records in the necessary environments if you run into something similar!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

run this command on your production server

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Also, make sure `bcrypt-ruby` gem is added to your Gemfile & `bundle install` gets executed successfully on PRODUCTION SERVER.

Also, open the code on production server and verify that your `User` model contains `has_secure_password` macro

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
end
```

also make sure there is a `password_digest` field in your database schema.

If it still doesn't work, post back with a sample app on github which reproduces this error, we can help you debug this.

Comment: Made sure has_secure_password was on the User.rb model on the production server and that RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate was run. Still getting this NoMethodError... only when I run unicorn with -E production. I'm working on a sample app to reproduce this error now.

Comment: For Unicorn, ensure that's its process gets spawen in correct ENV. so launch with `bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb -E production`. Do you still get an error?

Comment: When I run unicorn with -E production I get the error in the production log, when I run unicorn without -E production, my user authentication works. This does me no good because rails loads the development sqlite development database

Comment: I have added a link to a sample app that has the same problem using bcrypt's authenticate method

Comment: I've figured out that while the server is in production mode my sessions controller can't access the user model. So when I call User.find it isn't getting run therefore the authenticate method through has_secure_password isn't available. Why would the relationships between controller and model be different in production?